# Убрать блок если нет текста в его втором элементе

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько блоков класса `pinRow`

В этих блоках всегда есть текст в первом абзаце. Но, в зависимости от фильтрации, не всегда есть информация во втором.

Задача: скрыть блоки, в которых нет текста во втором абзаце.

> Нужно писать на JS без jQuery, вот скрипт который написал :

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("pinRow").forEach(function() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("display")[0].textContent == "") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pinRow")[0].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="pinInfo">
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Представительство</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Представительство</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Адрес</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Адрес</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Должность</b>:</p>
    <p class="display"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Телефон</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Телефон</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Моя крякозябра не работает, посоветуйте плз как можно это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const pinRow = document.getElementsByClassName("pinRow");

for(let i = 0; i < pinRow.length; i++ ) {
  if(pinRow[i].querySelector('.display').textContent == '') {
    pinRow[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pinInfo">
<div class="pinRow"><p><b>Представительство</b>:</p>
            <p class="display">Представительство</p>        
</div>
<div class="pinRow"><p><b>Адрес</b>:</p>
            <p class="display">Адрес</p>        
</div>
<div class="pinRow"><p><b>Должность</b>:</p>
            <p class="display"></p>     
</div>
<div class="pinRow"><p><b>Телефон</b>:</p>
            <p class="display">Телефон</p>      
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с `forEach`

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('pinRow')].forEach(s => {
  if (s.querySelector('.display').textContent == '') {
    s.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="pinInfo">
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Представительство</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Представительство</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Адрес</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Адрес</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Должность</b>:</p>
    <p class="display"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="pinRow">
    <p><b>Телефон</b>:</p>
    <p class="display">Телефон</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: А можно немного детальнее, как это через for сделать) а то я немного "Нуб, л*х , нет друзей". Спасибо)

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать `forEach`? Очень даже можно...

Comment: @Air перебери `getElementsByClassName` с `forEach` и расскажи, что получится.

Comment: Глянь свой ответ. Я  тебе даже плюс поставлю...))) И убери комментарии

Comment: @Air И это жульничество. То, что ты делаешь, (`[...someArray]`) уже превращает содержимое в нормальный JS массив. А сам метод `getElementsByClassName` возвращает объект [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), который не имеет метода forEach. Поэтому можешь обратно минусить, не важно, но комментарий я не удалю. У `getElementsByClassName` НЕТ метода forEach и это не JS массив.

Comment: Как тебе угодно....)))

Comment: @Air при чём тут как мне угодно? Спеку почитай. Или скажи, где я не прав. Иначе получается, что я человека в заблуждение ввожу.

Comment: @AlexSazonov, Я тоже останусь при своем мнении... Ну тогда удали мою правку и измени свой ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Это работает =) :

```
const display = document.querySelectorAll('.display')
display.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.textContent == "") {
    item.parentNode.remove()
  }
})
```

querySelectorAll возвращает массив который можно перебрать через forEach.
Далее мы проходим по каждому элементу с классом display и смотрим пустой ли он, если да - удаляем его родительский div.pinRow

Comment: кстати, используй remove() или display: none в зависимости от того насколько важно то что ты прячешь, ведь зайти в инспектор и открыть блок у которого display: none не составит труда продвинутому посетителю сайта)